# How to detect Ipad portrait and lanscape

Tags: jquery

This is my code. I want remove `jScrollPane` only Ipad portrait and don't need reload page. Please help me

```
$(window).resize( function(event){
            var height = $(window).height();
            var width = $(window).width();

            if(width>height) {
                var height = 0;
                height = $(window).height()-129;
                height = height-56-$('.titstyle04').height();
                $('.mainimgmenuin .jscrollpane').css('height',height);
                if($('.jscrollpane').length > 0){
                    $('.jscrollpane').jScrollPane();
                }
            }
            else {
               $(".jscrollpane").jScrollPane().data().jsp
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

$(window).on("orientationchange", function () {

```
if (window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth) {

    CallPortraitMail();

} else if (window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth) {

    CallLandscapeMail();

}
```

});

Use the orientation change method to customize ur code.

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a JavaScript/jQuery solution, here's an option (in jQuery):

```
$(function() {
    var myInterval = setInterval(function() {
      if(window.innerHeight > window.innerWidth){
        $('.jscrollpan').hide();
      } 
      if(window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth){
          $('.jscrollpan').show();
      }
  },4);
});
```

Also, optional, have you tried the following in your CSS (use this instead of the jQuery above)?

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) {
    .jscrollpane {
      display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: You could always try to snag it with an interval function, I've edited my jQuery solution if you wanna try that out.